# How do i solve this issue? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.botonContinuar.onclick

Tags: javascript

When i choose 3 products from the menu, it works, but if i choose 1 o 2 it doesn't.
I mean, it only works specifically when i choose 3 products, when choose 1 it tells me that there is an error on the line 177, the line that initializes productoDos. If i choose 2 it tells me that there is an error on the line 181, witch is the line that initializes productoTres.

If i write this it works with 1 product and with 2 products, the problem its that i cant make it work with more than 2

```
botonContinuar.onclick = function(){
        let formulario2 = document.querySelector("#formulario-2");
        let formaDePago = formulario2.TypeOfPaymentyOption.value;
        valid = true;
        event.preventDefault();
        // your validations
        if((formaDePago) == ""){
            alert("Completa los espacios requeridos.")
            
           valid = false;
           console.log("falso")
        }
        // and so on all your validations
        
        if(valid){
          
          let productoUno = document.querySelectorAll("#exampleModalLabel2")[0].textContent
          let precioUno =  document.querySelectorAll("#price-span2")[0].textContent
          let cantidadUno = document.querySelectorAll("#sel2")[0].value
          
          let productoDos = document.querySelectorAll("#exampleModalLabel2")[1].textContent
          let cantidadDos = document.querySelectorAll("#sel2")[1].value
          let precioDos =  document.querySelectorAll("#price-span2")[1].textContent
          
          let productoTres = document.querySelectorAll("#exampleModalLabel2")[2].textContent
          let cantidadTres = document.querySelectorAll("#sel2")[2].value
          let precioTres =  document.querySelectorAll("#price-span2")[2].textContent
          
          let total = document.querySelector("#total-estimado").textContent
          
          switch(numeroPedidos){
            case 1:
                let pedido1Item = `*PEDIDO: DM Indumentaria* %0a%0a— *[ ${cantidadUno} ]* ${productoUno} > *${precioUno}*%0a%0a*Total:* ${total}*%0aForma de pago: *${formaDePago}*%0a`;
                window.open("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5493815415219&text=" + pedido1Item);
                break
            case 2:

                let pedido2Item = `*PEDIDO: DM Indumentaria* %0a%0a— *[ ${cantidadUno} ]* ${productoUno} > *${precioUno}*%0a— *[ ${cantidadDos} ]* ${productoDos} > *${precioDos}* %0a %0a*Total:* ${total}*%0aForma de pago: *${formaDePago}*%0a`;
                window.open("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5493815415219&text=" + pedido2Item);
                break;
            case 3:
                let pedido3Item = `*PEDIDO: DM Indumentaria* %0a%0a— *[ ${cantidadUno} ]* ${productoUno} > *${precioUno}*%0a— *[ ${cantidadDos} ]* ${productoDos} > *${precioDos}*%0a— *[ ${cantidadTres} ]* ${productoTres} > *${precioTres}* %0a %0a*Total:* ${total}*%0aForma de pago: *${formaDePago}*%0a`;
                window.open("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5493815415219&text=" + pedido3Item);
                break;
            default:
            document.write("El usuario ingreso una operacion incorrecta");
          }
        }   
}
```

**UPDATED**: Updated version:

```
   botonContinuar.onclick = function(){
          let formulario1 = document.querySelector("#formulario-1");
          let formulario2 = document.querySelector("#formulario-2");
          let tipoDeEnvio = formulario1.TypeOfDeliveryOption.value;
          let formaDePago = formulario2.TypeOfPaymentyOption.value;
          valid = true;
          event.preventDefault();
          // your validations
          if((formaDePago && tipoDeEnvio) == ""){
              alert("Completa los espacios requeridos.")
              
             valid = false;
             console.log("falso")
          }
          // and so on all your validations
          if(valid){
            let productoUno = document.querySelectorAll("#exampleModalLabel2")[0].textContent
            let precioUno =  document.querySelectorAll("#price-span2")[0].textContent
            let cantidadUno = document.querySelectorAll("#sel2")[0].value
            let total = document.querySelector("#total-estimado").textContent
            if(numeroPedidos === 1){
              let pedido1Item = `*PEDIDO: DM Indumentaria* %0a%0a— *[ ${cantidadUno} ]* ${productoUno} > *${precioUno}*%0a%0a*Total:* ${total}%0a%0aTipo de envío: *${tipoDeEnvio}*%0aForma de pago: *${formaDePago}*%0a`;
              window.open("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5493815415219&text=" + pedido1Item);
            } else if (numeroPedidos > 1){
              let productoDos = document.querySelectorAll("#exampleModalLabel2")[1].textContent
              let cantidadDos = document.querySelectorAll("#sel2")[1].value
              let precioDos =  document.querySelectorAll("#price-span2")[1].textContent
              let pedido2Item = `*PEDIDO: DM Indumentaria* %0a%0a— *[ ${cantidadUno} ]* ${productoUno} > *${precioUno}*%0a— *[ ${cantidadDos} ]* ${productoDos} > *${precioDos}* %0a %0a*Total:* ${total}%0a%0aTipo de envío: *${tipoDeEnvio}*%0aForma de pago: *${formaDePago}*%0a`;
              window.open("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5493815415219&text=" + pedido2Item);
            }
          }   
}
```

HTML page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/icon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Plataforma mozo" />
    <meta name="description"
        content="Plataforma Mozos" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <title>Plataforma de pedidos</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light navbar-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img width="80px" src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
            <h3 class="font-weight-light">Plataforma para mozos</h1>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section>
            <!-- Hamburguesas -->
             <div class="container text-center my-4">
                <h4 class="p-2" style="color:#535353  ; font-weight: 600; border: 2px solid #CBC9C9  ; border-radius: 10px;">Hamburguesas</h4>
             </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="container">
                <!--Smashed-->
               <div class="menu-item position-relative mb-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-6" onclick="addToModalClicked(event)" data-target="#exampleModal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-toggle="modal">
                   <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                       <img src="#" alt="" style="width: 120px; height: 100px"class="not-display card-image">
                       <div>
                           <h5 class="ml-2 card-title">Smashed Burger con papas</h5>
                           <p class="ml-2 card-text">Pan casero, hamburguesa, tomate, lechuga, salsa de ajo, queso cheddar y papas fritas.<span class="not-display"></span></p>
                           <h6 class="ml-2 card-price" style="padding-top: 30px;color: green;">$ 270</h6>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>       
            <hr>    
            <div class="container">
                <!--Veggie-->
               <div class="menu-item position-relative mb-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-6" onclick="addToModalClicked(event)" data-target="#exampleModal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-toggle="modal">
                   <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                       <img src="#" alt="" style="width: 120px; height: 100px"class="not-display card-image">
                       <div>
                           <h5 class="ml-2 card-title">Veggie Burger con papas</h5>
                           <p class="ml-2 card-text">Pan casero, hamburguesa vegetariana, tomate, lechuga, salsa de ajo, queso cheddar y papas fritas.
                            <br>
                            Variedades: Garbanzo, Soja, Quinoa, Lenteja.<span class="not-display"></span></p>
                           <h6 class="ml-2 card-price" style="padding-top: 30px;color: green;">$ 250</h6>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>       
            <hr>    
            <div class="container">
                <!--NOTco-->
               <div class="menu-item position-relative mb-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-6" onclick="addToModalClicked(event)" data-target="#exampleModal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-toggle="modal">
                   <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                       <img src="#" alt="" style="width: 120px; height: 100px"class="not-display card-image">
                       <div>
                           <h5 class="ml-2 card-title">NOTco Burger con papas</h5>
                           <p class="ml-2 card-text">Pan casero, hamburguesa vegana NOTco, tomate, lechuga, salsa de ajo, queso cheddar y papas fritas.<span class="not-display"></span></p>
                           <h6 class="ml-2 card-price" style="padding-top: 30px;color: green;">$ 350</h6>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>       
            <hr>    
        </section>
        <section>
            <!-- Papas -->
             <div class="container text-center my-4">
                <h4 class="p-2" style="color:#535353  ; font-weight: 600; border: 2px solid #CBC9C9  ; border-radius: 10px;">Papas</h4>
             </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="container">
                <!--Medianas-->
               <div class="menu-item position-relative mb-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-6" onclick="addToModalClicked(event)" data-target="#exampleModal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-toggle="modal">
                   <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                       <img src="#" alt="" style="width: 120px; height: 100px"class="not-display card-image">
                       <div>
                        <h5 class="ml-2 card-title">Papas fritas grandes</h5>
                        <h6 class="ml-2 card-price" style="padding-top: 30px;color: green;">$ 180</h6>
                        <p class="ml-2 card-text"><span class="not-display"></span></p>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>       
            <hr>      
            <div class="container">
                <!--Grandes-->
               <div class="menu-item position-relative mb-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-6" onclick="addToModalClicked(event)" data-target="#exampleModal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-toggle="modal">
                   <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                       <img src="#" alt="" style="width: 120px; height: 100px"class="not-display card-image">
                       <div>
                        <h5 class="ml-2 card-title">Papas fritas medianas</h5>
                        <h6 class="ml-2 card-price" style="padding-top: 30px;color: green;">$ 150</h6>
                        <p class="ml-2 card-text"><span class="not-display"></span></p>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>       
            <hr>   
            <div class="container">
                <!--Medianas cheddar-->
               <div class="menu-item position-relative mb-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-6" onclick="addToModalClicked(event)" data-target="#exampleModal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-toggle="modal">
                   <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                       <img src="#" alt="" style="width: 120px; height: 100px"class="not-display card-image">
                       <div>
                        <h5 class="ml-2 card-title">Papas cheddar grandes</h5>
                        <h6 class="ml-2 card-price" style="padding-top: 30px;color: green;">$ 230</h6>
                        <p class="ml-2 card-text"><span class="not-display"></span></p>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>       
            <hr>      
            <div class="container">
                <!--Grandes cheddar-->
               <div class="menu-item position-relative mb-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-6" onclick="addToModalClicked(event)" data-target="#exampleModal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-toggle="modal">
                   <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                       <img src="#" alt="" style="width: 120px; height: 100px"class="not-display card-image">
                       <div>
                        <h5 class="ml-2 card-title">Papas cheddar medianas</h5>
                        <h6 class="ml-2 card-price" style="padding-top: 30px;color: green;">$ 200</h6>
                        <p class="ml-2 card-text"><span class="not-display"></span></p>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>       
            <hr>      
        </section>


    </main>
    <section>
         <!-- Modal de productos-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                 <div class="modal-content">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="color: black!important; position: absolute; right: 5px;font-size: 3rem;font-weight: 300!important; ">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <img class="modalimage" style="width:230px; margin: 0 auto;" src="" id="exampleModalImage" alt="">
                    <div class="modal-header row" style="border-bottom:0; padding: 0!important;">
                           <h3 class="modal-title mt-3" id="exampleModalLabel" style="margin: 0 auto; padding: 0 50px; text-align: center;">Modal title</h3>
                     </div>
                    <div class="modal-body text-center" id="modalText" style="padding: 0.6rem!important;">...</div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="sel1" class="ml-4" style="font-weight: 700!important;">CANTIDAD:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="sellist1">
                             <option>1</option>
                             <option>2</option>
                             <option>3</option>
                             <option>4</option>
                             <option>5</option>
                         </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button id="boton-agregar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin: 0 auto;">Agregar 
                             <span class="span-button" style="padding: 6px; background-color: #3e33ef; margin-right: 10px;">1 Item</span>
                             <span id="price-span"> $0 </span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <!-- Modal de pedidos-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

                    <div class="modal-content" id="content-pedidos">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"
                            style="color:black!important; right: 0px; position: absolute; left: 5px;font-size: 3rem; ">
                            <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-arrow-left-short" fill="currentColor"
                                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                    d="M7.854 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L5.207 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l3-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z" />
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.5 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h6.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z" />
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"
                            style="color: black!important; position: absolute; right: 5px;font-size: 3rem;font-weight: 300!important; ">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="modal-products">
                            <div class="modal-header mt-5">
                                <div>
                                    <h5 class="modal-title-pedidos" id="exampleModalLabel2">Modal title </h5>
                                    <span class="card-price" id="price-span2"> $0 </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select onclick="actualizarCantidadPedidos(event)" class="form-control" id="sel2"
                                        name="sellist2">
                                        <option>1</option>
                                        <option>2</option>
                                        <option>3</option>
                                        <option>4</option>
                                        <option>5</option>
                                        <option>6</option>
                                        <option>7</option>
                                        <option>8</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="sel1" class="ml-4" style="font-weight: 700!important;">MESA:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="numMesa" name="numeroMesa">
                                 <option>1</option>
                                 <option>2</option>
                                 <option>3</option>
                                 <option>4</option>
                                 <option>5</option>
                                 <option>6</option>
                                 <option>7</option>
                                 <option>8</option>
                                 <option>9</option>
                                 <option>10</option>
                                 <option>11</option>
                                 <option>12</option>
                                 <option>13</option>
                                 <option>14</option>
                                 <option>15</option>
                                 <option>16</option>
                                 <option>17</option>
                                 <option>18</option>
                                 <option>19</option>
                                 <option>20</option>
                             </select>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div style="text-align:center;">
                                <p>Total estimado: <span id="total-estimado"></span></p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <form class="m-5" id="formulario-2">
                                    <h6 style="text-align: center;">Forma de pago <span style="color: red;">*</span></h6>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label for="inlineRadioPayment1" class="btn-block">Efectivo</label>
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="TypeOfPaymentyOption"
                                            id="inlineRadioPayment1" value="Efectivo">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <label for="inlineRadioPayment2" class="btn-block">Mercado Pago/Tarjeta</label>
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="TypeOfPaymentyOption"
                                            id="inlineRadioPayment2" value="Mercado Pago">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer" style="padding: 0.3rem;">
                                <button id="boton-continuar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                                    style="font-weight: 30; margin: 0 auto;">Confirmar comanda<i
                                        class="fa fa-whatsapp" style="padding-left: 5px;"></i> </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Boton de pedidos-->
            <div class="mb-5 btn btn-primary fixed-bottom not-display container shadow-lg" style="width:80%!important;" data-target="#exampleModal2" data-toggle="modal" id="boton-pedidos">
                <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag" style="padding-right: 5px;"></i>
                Tu pedido: <span id="price-span-pedidos">$0</span>
            </div>
    </section>
    <footer class="text-light py-3">
        <p class="text-center lead">Sean bienvenidos siempre</p>
        <p class="text-center">La Romana Eventos 2020</p>
    </footer>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b6f4b16237.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That error means that one of your `document.querySelectorAll` statements returns undefined (the item you're looking for doesn't exist). 

Also, why are you using `document.querySelectorAll` with IDs? Each ID should only have one item corresponding to it.

Comment: you must check the length of products selected and use dynamic coding

Comment: Please add HTML of the page to your question

Comment: I just added @Vitalli

Comment: I don't really know how to use dynamic coding @SagarV

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("#exampleModalLabel2")[0]` makes zero sense. You cannot have more than one element with that `id` on your page. Use `document.getElementById('exampleModalLabel2')` instead.

Comment: I'm pretty much new to programing. It's been 5 months since i've started. There are probably tons of errors in my code. Thing here it's that i know what the error means, i've tried everything to solve that but i think i just can't without help @AniketG

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.** Nobodys willing to scan through hundreds of lines of irrelevant code parts.

Comment: @connexo I've asked for full HTML to make sure it's clear what `document.querySelectorAll()` returns.

Comment: @Goyi well the first thing you should fix is to make it so each ID only matches with one item. If multiple items have the same ID, you should remove the ID and give them the same class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the page already has the code to build a list of items in the shopping cart and the task is to iterate through the results of `document.querySelectorAll("#exampleModalLabel2")` and other queries to dynamically build an order summary.

This should help. It gets all titles/prices and quantities and based on the amount it will build `items` array and the order summary message.

[Array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is used to add elements to array, [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to concatenate strings together and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to build the summary.

```
botonContinuar.onclick = function(){
    let formulario2 = document.querySelector("#formulario-2");
    let formaDePago = formulario2.TypeOfPaymentyOption.value;
    valid = true;
    event.preventDefault();
    // your validations
    if ((formaDePago) === "") {
        alert("Completa los espacios requeridos.")

        valid = false;
    }
    // and so on all your validations

    if (valid) {
        const names = document.querySelectorAll("#exampleModalLabel2");
        const prices = document.querySelectorAll("#price-span2");
        const quantities = document.querySelectorAll("#sel2");
        let items = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            const name = names[i].textContent;
            const quantity = quantities[i].value;
            const price = prices[i].textContent;
            items.push(`— *[ ${quantity} ]* ${name} > *${price}*%0a`)
        }

        let total = document.querySelector("#total-estimado").textContent;

        const text = `*PEDIDO: DM Indumentaria* %0a%0a${items.join('')}%0a*Total:* ${total}*%0aForma de pago: *${formaDePago}*%0a`;
        console.log(text);
        window.open("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5493815415219&text=" + text);

        alert('Order has been sent');
    }
}
```

**P.S.**

It is recommended to have unique ID tags on the page.

So I would advice changing all those repeated IDs

> `id="sel2"`, `id="exampleModalLabel2"`, `id="price-span2"`

to class names

> `class="sel2 form-control"`, `class="exampleModalLabel2  modal-title-pedidos"` and `class="price-span2 card-price"`

and adjusting selectors from `#id` to `.class` in the code above

> `document.querySelectorAll(".sel2")`

Comment: Thank you! I was really new to programming and didn't have much idea. Maybe I will continue with that project soon.